# How to add mouse move event on a wms layer example in mapbox gl js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, wms

I tried to add mouse move event on this wms layer in my code. But doesn't works. Used this example to test https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/wms/

```
map.on('mousemove' , 'wms-test-layer' , function(e) {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that it doesn't work because `mousemove` relies on [`queryRenderedFeatures`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/2020f3f9ced516086508925411bd098fbb4c3234/src/ui/map.js#L707). Probably you can fill an issue in the [mapbox-gl-js](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js) repo.